# How to retrieve lost rigify controls?

Tags: rigify

I rigged my model with a basic human metarig. Along the way I must have somehow accidentally deleted/removed the controls. The animation I had already done is still there but the controls to edit it aren't there any more. Is there a way to retrieve or reinstate the controls? Hoping I don't have to redo the animation from scratch.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you accidentally deleted the widget objects for the control bones? They are usually in a deactivated collection named *WGTS_rig*. Have you tried to recreate the animation rig from the meta rig?